# How to validate the data format in Logstash after parsing with KV filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have log messages like:

```
2017-01-06 19:27:53,893 INFO [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] com.symantec.olp.sas.log.SummaryLogAspect - {country=JP, svid=182, typ=sassum, vid=1120, xffmode=0, initallocdate=2014-12-15T01:08:24Z, xffip=222.230.107.165, seatcnt=1, plgid=2, api=941753644, oslocale=JPN, fng=CJ6FRE1208VMNRQG, req=/228228131/28RXAAPB1DqJj/RSLHL940/EMBXtu+/f+/Zeb/KV1Q/DTXZBFC94ZE5AOmz/mDCqB7zJOARDQO/166180202502162557303662649078783407201612&D09DEEFB7E78065D?NAM=SFlBUy1WQTE2&MFN=VkFJTyBDb3Jwb3JhdGlvbg==&MFM=VkpQMTEx&OLA=JPN&OLO=JPN, llmv=470, oslang=JPN, ctok=166180202502162557303662649078783407201612, resptime=119, epid=70D3B811A994477F957A90985109BE9D, campnid=0, remip=222.230.107.165, lictype=SOS, dbepid=70D3B811A994477F957A90985109BE9D, cid=nav1sasapppex02.msp.symantec.com1481215212435, status=10002, siid=240, skum=21356539, skup=01001230, psn=O749UPCN8KSY, cip=84.100.138.144, mname=VAIO Corporation, puid=1199, skuf=01100470, st=1481765738387, prbid=5967, mmodel=VJP111, clang=EN, pnfi=1120, cprbid=745, cpmv=7428, euip=222.230.107.165, prcdline=2, dvnm=HYAS-VA16, remdays=0, seatid=ah00s8CIdqUQyW2V, sasvid=106, xlsid=3730, baseactkey=186635290403122706518307794, coupon=651218, translogid=75033f05-9cf2-48e2-b924-fc2441d11d33}  
2017-01-06 19:28:03,894 INFO [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] com.symantec.olp.sas.log.SummaryLogAspect - {country=JP, svid=182, typ=sassum, vid=1120, xffmode=0, initallocdate=2014-12-15T01:08:24Z, xffip=222.230.107.165, seatcnt=1, plgid=2, api=228228131, oslocale=JPN, fng=1TA6U8RVL0JQXA0N, req=/228228131/28RXAAPB1DqJj/RSLHL940/EMBXtu+/f+/Zeb/KV1Q/DTXZBFC94ZE5AOmz/mDCqB7zJOARDQO/166180202502162557303662649078783407201612&D09DEEFB7E78065D?NAM=SFlBUy1WQTE2&MFN=VkFJTyBDb3Jwb3JhdGlvbg==&MFM=VkpQMTEx&OLA=JPN&OLO=JPN, lpmv=470, oslang=JPN, ctok=166180202502162557303662649078783407201612, resptime=119, epid=70D3B811A994477F957A90985109BE9D, campnid=0, remip=222.230.107.165, lictype=SOS, dbepid=70D3B811A994477F957A90985109BE9D, cid=nav1sasapppex02.msp.symantec.com1481215212435, status=0000, siid=240, skum=21356539, skup=01001230, psn=28MHHH2VPR4T, cip=222.230.107.165, mname=VAIO Corporation, puid=1199, skuf=01100470, st=1481765738387, prbid=5967, mmodel=VJP111, clang=EN, pnfi=1120, cprbid=745, cpmv=1027, euip=222.230.107.165, prcdline=2, dvnm=HYAS-VA16, remdays=0, seatid=StrlisGXA4yAt1ad, sasvid=130, xlsid=2820, baseactkey=028200017462383754273799438, coupon=123456, translogid=72df4536-6038-4d1c-b213-d0ff5c3c20fb}
```

I use the below grok pattern to match against these:

```
(?m)%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:severity} \[%{GREEDYDATA:thread}\] %{JAVACLASS:className} - \{%{GREEDYDATA:logmsg}\}
```

Post that, I use the KV filter to split the fields in logmsg field and include only those fields that are of interest to me. My question is: How can I validate the format of those fields that are of interest to me? One thing I need to mention is - the log contains different numbers of fields in logmsg that's why I've used GREEDYDATA

My Logstash.conf is as follows:

```
input {   
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "brokers_list"
    topics => ["transaction-log"]
    codec => "json"   
  } 
}

filter {
        grok {
            match => [ "message", "(?m)%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:severity} \[%{GREEDYDATA:thread}\] %{JAVACLASS:className} - \{%{GREEDYDATA:logmsg}\}" ]
            #overwrite => [ "message" ]
        }

        if "_grokparsefailure" not in [tags] {
           kv {
              field_split => ", "
              source => "logmsg"
              include_keys => ["api", "fng", "status", "cip", "cpmv", "translogid", "coupon", "baseactkey", "xlsid", "sasvid", "seatid", "srcHostname", "serverId" ]
              allow_duplicate_values => false
              remove_field => [ "message", "kafka.*", "logmsg"]
           }
        }

        if [api] != "228228131" {
           mutate { add_tag => "_grokparsefailure" }
        }

        date { # use timestamp from the log
          "match" => [ "timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
          target => "@timestamp"
        }

        mutate {
          remove_field => [ "timestamp" ]  # remove unused stuff
        } 
  }

output {   
  if "_grokparsefailure" not in [tags] {      
    kafka {
        topic_id => "invalid topic"
        bootstrap_servers => "brokers_list"
        codec => json {}      
    }    
  } else {    
    kafka {
        topic_id => "valid topic"
        bootstrap_servers => "brokers_list"
        codec => json { }     
    }    
  } 
}
```

After parsing with KV filter, I'm checking the value of api field and if it is NOT equal to 228228131, then I add _grokparsefailure tag to it and don't process further.

I want to be able to validate the format of the fields listed in Include_keys like cip which is client IP? How can I validate the data format for those fields? Since my log contains different number of fields, at the grok level I can't validate. Only after parsing with KV I can get those fields and validate them. By validation i mean, validate that they conform to the type defined in ES Index. This is because in case, they are not conforming, I want to send them to invalid-topic in Kafka.

Should I use ruby filter to validate? If so, can you give me a sample? Or should I rebuild the event after KV parsing and again use grok on that newly created event.

Will v much appreciate some sample showing these.

Answer (score 0):

A concrete example would have helped, but you can check for a lot of things with regular expressions:

```
if [myField] =~ /^[0-9]+$/ {
     # it contains a number
}
```

or something like this:

```
if [myField] =~ /^[a-z]+$/ {
    # it contains lower lowercase letters
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Turns out that I can use ruby filter to loop through K,V pairs and then can do the validation you suggested. But I heard it's not good for performance. And that **logstash isn't meant for validation in first place**. And that ideally such stuff should be done using grok.